# In JavaScript, why not capital letters when using 'var'?

Tags: javascript, variables

What is the reason of using only lower case letters when using *var* in JavaScript?

I mean, we can write *var*, but not *VAR*.

Comment: You can use uppercase

Comment: What are you referring to when you say only lowercase? Do you mean the variable names or the word `var` itself?

Comment: "Can you tell me the reason of using only lower case letters when using var in javascript?". Personal preference? What are you talking about? Where did you get the obviously mistaken impression that you can only use lowercase letters? Voting to close as off topic.

Comment: This is what is called guidelines. The same reason as why you start sentences from capital letter. As already specified, it it is not always lower case.

Comment: If you mean the reserved word `var`, it's because Javascript is case-sensitive language.  IOW:  `var` is not the same thing as `VAR`, or `Var`, or even `vaR` etc.

Comment: The current syntax highlighter here uses the convention, so using an uppercase first letter for a variable will result in weird syntax highlighting.

Answer (score 2):

Programming languages have keywords (such as `var`, `while`, `if`) and keywords are by definition very strict. In *JavaScript* (as well as many other languages), **all keywords are Case Sensitive** and their case happens to be **lower case**.

So this works:

```js
var x = 3;
console.log(x);
```

But this blows up with a **SyntaxError**:

```js
VAR x = 3;
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Variable names

It's not an enforced, language rule.

```
var HELLOIMSHOUTING = "HI THERE";
```

Is perfectly valid JavaScript.

The recommendation of using lowercase letters is a stylistic choice, allowing developers to scan over code and see what is a local variable and what isn't, just from the style of writing.

Worth noting: It's normal to have a lowercase *first* letter in JavaScript for a local variable, but proceeding words in the same variable will have a capital letter for readability. Example:

```
var myCoolVariable = 1;
```

Which is more readable (at a glance) than:

```
var mycoolvariable = 1;
```

#### 'var' vs. 'VAR'

Programming languages are finicky things that like certain things a particular way. To simplify development, JavaScript will expect variables to be declared in a particular, restrictive way (`var`, `const`, `let`) and any variation in how they're declared will be rejected.

This saves the compiler needing to look for every permutation of `var` before actually looking for variable name and value.

Answer (score 0):

It is entirely down to convention.

Variables traditionally:

- Start with a capital letter if they are a constructor function
- Are written in `ALL CAPS` if they are a global constant
- Are either `all_lower_case` or as `camelCase` otherwise

It makes no difference to the JavaScript compiler, but programmers maintaining the code will have expectations about what the use of capital letters indicates.